# How can I run tests only in a given category, either locally through Test Explorer, or in a Build?

Tags: nunit

If you have the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SuccessTests
{
    [Test]
    [Category("Long")]
    public void VeryLongTest()
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

How can you - from within VS Test Explorer, or as part of a build config - run only those tests marked as belonging to the "Long" category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your build, you can run the nunit console runner:

```
nunit-console.exe TestAssembly.dll /include:Long
```

More here: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2

Comment: Thanks Chris - how would you run this on your local machine via Visual Studio?

Comment: I would run this from the commandline as part of a build script as a batch file or a powershell script. Ideally, with psake IMO. If you really needed in VS you could add it to a Build Event in your project's Configuration (as post-build) or assign it to an External Tool and map a keyboard shortcut to that command.

Comment: Cool, console works.  Is the console app something I have to download separately?  I don't see it locally or on the downloads page.

Comment: It is, you can get it through NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Runners/